# Measurable function Example

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose I have a state space omega which equals $\mathbb{R}$(real number entire set) and sigma algebra $F=\{(-\infty ,0],(0,\infty),\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$ and the random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by:
$$ X(t)= \begin{cases} 2 & t<0\\  4 & t\geq 0\end{cases} $$
Then, how to prove whether $X$ is $F$-measurable or not $F$-measurable?

I am having problems with notations and I am very much new to measurable functions. I know I need to look at pre-images, so if I look at the value $X−1[\{4\}]$, then, it would mean all those values of $t$ which lie in the interval $[0,∞)$, but since, $0$ is in open set for $0$ to $∞$, its not $F$-measurable, am I correct on this?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. $X$ is $F$-measurable, if all preimages of Borel-sets are in $F$. Have a look at $X^{-1}[\{4\}]$.

Comment: Hi, I am having problems with notations and I am very much new to measurable functions. I know i need to look at pre-images, so if i look at      the value X−1[{4}], then, it would mean all those values of t which lie in  the interval [0,∞), but since, 0 is in open set for 0 to ∞, its not F-measurable, am i correct on this?

Comment: It does not depend on $\{0\} $ being open (which is wrong by the way), but of $[0,\infty)$ not being an element of $F $. Hence $X $ is not measurable.